# why CocoasPod increase IPA size? how to reduce the size?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

CocoasPod is good, But sometimes it's not. 
Why? Because there is a flag call "-ObjC" in your project.
It will pull ALL OBJECT FILES into your resulting binary.

For example, an empty project with "pod 'AFNetworking'" and the flag "-ObjC" is on, that will cause the binary will be 7MB. 7MB for an empty project, that's suck.

Some frameworks like Google Map SDK need the flag "-ObjC" is on.
So, if your project with "AFNetworking pod" and "Google Map SDK", it will cause the binary will be 17MB.

So my question is:
How can I turn off the "-ObjC" flag for special Library?
For example, just keep the "-ObjC" for Google Map SDK, but turn it off on AFNetworking.

Comment: I have facebook sdks (which is written in objective c) in my swift project. Any solution with swift?

Answer (score 3):

You should try the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068772/working-with-cocoapods-ios) so as to reduce the .ipa size.

> In general, adding a static library to your project in Objective-C
>   will pull ALL OBJECT FILES into your resulting binary because cocoa
>   pods installation adds -ObjC flag to your linker settings, and as
>   stated in linker manual:
>
> ```
> -ObjC        Loads all members of static archive libraries that implement
>              an Objective-C class or category.
> ```
>
> This flag included to solve problem with linking categories, because
>   by default linker will not include object files containing only
>   categories into resulting binary.

Comment: -1 for copying other answer instead of voting to close as duplicate.

Comment: +1 for copying and linking to an existing answer in addition to closing as duplicate.

Comment: @thilo, he did not close it.

Comment: do you know how to delete the flag on special library? for example, the google map sdk require -ObjC flag, but I don't want the AFNetworking with that flag

Comment: What is the final solution for this question?