# How to prevent the developer from adding -ObjC flag when implementing Categories

Tags: objective-c, linker, xcode5, categories, flags

It is well known that there is an issue related to objective-c and the way it exports symbols requires -ObjC flag to be set in the "Other Linker Flags" of the build settings when implemented categories. If not set xcode throws a linker error.

Every time a developer would use the lib that I made has to be using this linker flag which is  quite frustrating. Is there a workaround for this problem ?

I would just want to make the process simpler just load the lib and compile. Not having to set the flag is what I'm aiming for.

Appreciate your time in finding a solution. Hopefully this could be a new start.

Comment: If you find a solution, there are a lot of third party framework developers that would love to hear it. "Set the -ObjC flag" is a very common instruction for integrating 3rd party SDK's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently possible.

However, distributing your library as a [CocoaPod](http://cocoapods.org) makes the process of including your library [extremely easy](http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html). CocoaPods takes care of setting that flag automatically, as well as automating any extra flags, linking dependencies (*e.g.* libs and frameworks), and copying assets.  It is even possible to do this with [libraries you don't want freely share](http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html).

Comment: CocoaPods will add `-ObjC` by default for a static library: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20283853/562154